# Manifest in pom file - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, manifest

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kwestionariusz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
       <plugins>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
        <mainClass>pl.xx.kwestionariusz.gui.Kwestionariusz</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>  
</build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

error  that I am getting when I try to run it via cmd:

```
\NetBeansProjects\kwestionariusz\target>java -jar kwestionariusz-1.0.jar



Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hiber
nate/service/ServiceRegistry
        at pl.xx.kwestionariusz.dao.ListaZainteresowanDao.wyszukajZaintereso
wania(ListaZainteresowanDao.java:31)
        at pl.xx.kwestionariusz.gui.Kwestionariusz$2.<init>(Kwestionariusz.j
ava:110)
        at pl.xx.kwestionariusz.gui.Kwestionariusz.initComponents(Kwestionar
iusz.java:106)
        at pl.xx.kwestionariusz.gui.Kwestionariusz.<init>(Kwestionariusz.jav
a:33)
        at pl.xx.kwestionariusz.gui.Kwestionariusz$5.run(Kwestionariusz.java
:275)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegist
ry
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 19 more
```

[image]

What do I have to add to pom file to make this project executable? It works when I compile and run it in netbeans but doesnt work when I try to use jar file.

@edit
still no solution

@edit
im starting bounty..

Comment: I came here to find out what a .porn file was. Damn you kerning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the classpath. What you specify in .pom file are only the dependencies needed to build the project. However actually running the resulting .jar is another matter, and .pom has no power there.

It works in NetBeans IDE, because as any good IDE it keeps track of dependencies you added to the project and adds them to classpath when trying to run. Your cmd command does not replicate that.

There are two solutions to this problem:

- Adding everything required to classpath. That would probably involve creating a .bat file containing the path to every required library using `-cp` argument
- Creating your .jar file so that it contains all the required dependencies.

Solution number two sounds much better in theory, and can be achieved in Maven with (for example) [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) or [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html)

Configuration of `Maven Shade Plugin` from one of my projects:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Main-Class>my.package.tree.Main</Main-Class>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <!-- Exclude files that sign a jar (one or multiple of the dependencies). 
                        One may not repack a signed jar without this, or you will get a SecurityException 
                        at program start. -->
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.INF</exclude> <!-- This one may not be required -->
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks to your answer I did what here is done:
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-shade-plugin/

and I finally got my working .jar file!
Thanks.

But the problem is... how can I hide files inside of jar file? I mean whole hibernate.cfg is there and I dont want user to be able to read it

Comment: @arienn I'm afraid there is no way of obfuscating the insides of a jar file - it is just a zip archive after all. I don't know if there is even a theoreticat possibility of protecting it somehow - after all, your program needs to read it either way, so malevolent user will always be able to break your security. But that's a whole another question, beyond the scope of comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234468/executable-jar-file-hibernate-cfg-file here's my question. Ill give you bounty prize tomorrow, cuz I have to wait 24h to give it

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the dependency list in your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

It seems that your NetBeans IDE somehow already has this JAR in its classpath, which likely means that you already have this JAR somewhere on your computer.

Comment: after I added, error happened:
`pl/xx/kwestionariusz/util/HibernateUtil.java:[9,34] error: package org.hibernate.boot.registry does not exist`

Comment: You are probably missing other Hibernate JARs.

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>`

I changed it to that and it compiled but there is still same error when I try to lunch it (nothing happen) or when I try to lunch it using cmd (error as posted above)
        </dependency>

Comment: bounty is started, I really need some help in this one