# Executable jar file - hibernate.cfg file

Tags: java, hibernate, executable-jar

I created executable jar application that uses database connection. The problem is that my hibernate.cfg file is included in source any everyone can easily gain username and passowrd for DB.

How can I avoid this situation? Make it unreadable or somehow put it somewhere else that no-one can read it.

Comment: use encrypted password

Answer (score 0):

Plain text passwords are usually fine on properly secured machines; if someone who wants to do something bad has admin rights to the machine ,  they can easily do bad without knowing the password to your database. There is no need to worry about it, unless you have a malicious admin, but there not much anyone can do if you've got one of them. You can have encrypted password but I would give preference for securing the server itself and not worrying about passwords in config files.

You can check http://www.jasypt.org/ for encryption

Comment: Then how to decrypt that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jasypt: Java simplified encryption API for encrypting your username and password, its a simple API.

Hibernate.cfg. configuration

`<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.jasypt.hibernate3.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordC3P0ConnectionProvider</property>

<property name="connection.encryptor_registered_name">standardPBEStringEncryptor</property> 
<property name="connection.password">ENC(QVvFsdfefwewEz3i+0EwsxWenjtrjtrjweftUYpMs)</property>`

You need to use this API to encrypt your password and provide that password in the hibernate configuration.